# Abstract Java Grid

Tags: java, web-applications, grid

I'm looking for an abstract representation of a grid in Java (grid as in that thing with columns and rows of data).  Do such things exist?  I want to be able to sort, filter, keep track of rows, set column properties etc.  I'll then be realising the grid on the web.

To be clear: I've already decided on the ultimate view technology (client side).  The thing I'm looking for will hold all the records and offer them up as the view demands.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this tutorial from Sun about the tables in java. It gives a good idea on how to implement the model.

[Tutorial on tables in Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Yes, but only in Java 1.6 did sorting become possible.

Answer (score 0):

[JTable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the table models of the Glazed Lists project (provided that you can hook your web view to a regular TableModel)